# Java Inner Class Access Issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I can't figure out why the compiler keeps complaining about my code below:

operator1.push(); this call seems legit from runStack class

is there any restriction related to static inner classes in Java that I should be aware?

Comment: You should have posted the compiler's complaint

Comment: You should also follow Java naming conventions, and reformat your code to sanity.

Comment: You haven't shown the error message you're getting.

Comment: Can you describe exactly your problem and what is the compilator complaint?

Comment: And once I looked at the compiler error, I have a follow up question: what part of **required: pushPop  found: no arguments  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length** do you not understand?

Comment: thanks guys!  I was missing the arguments....which I did not need.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: your `push()` and `pop()` methods are declared to have parameters, but you're not supplying them. Just removing the parameters from the method declarations makes your code *compile* - but it's still horrible code.

I would forget about threading for the moment, and concentrate on reorganizing your code:

- Follow the Java naming conventions
- Don't overuse nested classes (as you are here)
- Make each class contain appropriate methods, and consider whether they should be static or instance methods
- Fix your indentation

When you *do* decide you're ready to try this threading code again (after you've made sure you understand what static means, etc) you should start again from scratch - it'll be quicker than trying to pull working code out of the mess, I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah....I agree.  I have dirty code.....just trying to get somenthing going here quick and dirty, so I can finish my disgn plan....just need to confirm some functionality.

Comment: @user852415: Glad to see you've removed the "rookie" insult. I hope you've learned that writing "quick and dirty" code is almost never worthwhile. Just separating the classes out, giving them better names, getting your IDE to indent the code etc would have made your code easier to understand - so that you'd probably have been able to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply arguments to operator1.push() and operator1.pop()

Answer (score 0):

When I try to compile I get the following error

```
myStack.java:129: error: method push in class pushPop cannot be applied to given types;
                    operator1.push();
                             ^
  required: pushPop
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

That seems pretty clear

Comment: right on....just running the code gave you the error...I can't beleive I missed that one.   Thanks!